# checking end of file in java by comparing with null

Tags: java

The code sample is taken from java official site with link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html

In the following lines of code, I didn't understand

1) why FileInputStream object is set to null initially?
2) the logic of the if condition in finally block

```
public Class A{

public static void main(String[] args){

        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
            out = new FileOutputStream("outagain.txt");
            int c;

            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(c);
            }
        } 
         finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    } 

}
```

Comment: 1. Try to remove the initialization with null and compile the code, and you'll understand why. 2. If FileInputStream() throws an exception, what will be the value of `in` and `out` in the finally block? What would happen if it didn't check for null? Note: that has absolutely nothing to do with "checking the end of file".

Comment: You can write code that does the same using a `try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("outagain.txt"), FileInputStream in = new FIleInputStream("xanadu.txt")) { ... } catch (IOException e) { ... }` statement which does not need a `finally` block.

Comment: This sample code must have been written more than 10 years ago, before the try-with-resources statement was available. Now you shouldn't code it like that and should instead use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: what does while((c=in.read() !=-1) statement do here? there is no increment operation being used within the while block either... would u pls help me understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) FileInputStream and FileOutputStream have to be initialized with some value. Therefore they are initialized with null.

They will be reinitialized in your try/catch block. Therefore two files are read.
If this process failes, because the files don't exist, the program will jump out of the try block and execute the "finally"-block. Else it will execute the while loop and execute the finally block afterwards.

2) The condition in your finally block compares "in" with "null". The files get only closend when out/in isn't null. In the first step 1) we set them to null. By comparing them with null at this point, we can see if opening the file worked correctly.

If it worked correctly in/out will not be null at this point and therefore we have a valid file to close. If it still is null, the file didn't open correctly and therefore doesn't have to be closed.

This process is typical error handling. We don't want the program to crash because a file couldn't be read.